# Test Error Maven RoboGuice [No implementation for "class" was bound]

Tags: android, maven, roboguice

I have an Android Project which contains two source folders src and test. In test, I have my test classes and some mock classes. I'm using RoboGuice dependency injection for Android in some class I wrote tests for.

The tests run perfectly fine in Eclipse on an emulator but fail using maven clean install.

```
No implementation for com.Store<com.MessageEvent> was bound.
```

The tests fail at setUp when using the injector.

```
mm = Guice.createInjector(new TestModule()).getInstance(MM.class);
```

And here is my binding module:

```
    public class TestModule implements Module{
    @Override
    public void configure(com.google.inject.Binder binder) {
        binder.bind(Context.class).toInstance(getContext());
        binder.bind(Scheduler.class).to(MockScheduler.class);
        binder.bind(EventManager.class).to(MockEventManager.class);
        binder.bind(new TypeLiteral<Store<Message>>(){}).to(new TypeLiteral<JsonStore<Message>>(){});
        binder.bind(new TypeLiteral<Store<MessageEvent>>(){}).to(new TypeLiteral<JsonStore<MessageEvent>>(){});
    }

    @Provides 
    JsonStore<MessageEvent> provideMessageEventJsonStore(Context context){
        return new JsonStore<MessageEvent>(context, "message_events_test.json", MessageEvent.class);
    }

    @Provides
    JsonStore<Message> provideMessageJsonStore(Context context){
        return new JsonStore<Message>(context, "message_manager_test.json", Message.class); 
    }
}
```

Why would the exception be thrown while running tests in Maven but not in Eclipse?

Comment: I somehow fixed my problem although I'm not sure why it works.
I extracted the interface of EvenManager and binded the interface to the mock. I then moved my mock package - which was under my tests source folder - under my src source folder.

And maven runs fine now.

Answer (score 0):

"No implementation was bound" means that you need to add a line for this particuar class in your modules file.

Comment: isn't that what I am doing?
 `binder.bind(new TypeLiteral<Store<MessageEvent>>(){}).to(new TypeLiteral<JsonStore<MessageEvent>>(){});`

Comment: What version of Roboguice are you using?

Comment: `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.roboguice</groupId>
            <artifactId>roboguice</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Can you verify that the format of the modules file is correct? Mine is different. It has "bind(.....).to(.....), not "binder.bind(....."  and the configure method takes no arguments. I assume you use Robolectric? If not, I recommend you use Robolectric for unit testing.

Comment: I have a binder variable passed to the configure method because I implement Module instead of extending the AbstractModule. I don't use Robolectric, I run my tests in the emulator. I'll look into it, thank you so much for your time!